# Why does C++ offer declarations in if statements?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, syntax

I recently learned that an `if statements` can be used to **declare variables**  in C++. I personally don't *really* understand the reason behind it.

Shouldn't `if statements` only check *if the conditions are properly meant*, and declaring a variable would result in an error?

That is, from what I believe, `if statements` can *only compares two separate values*. So declaring anything in an `if statement` really doesn't make sense as you aren't *comparing* anything.

### **Original Post:**

Why does the c++ compiler accept this:

```
#include <iostream>

int Test()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    if (int n = Test())
    {
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
}
```

More specifically: Why is  if (int n = Test()) a valid statement?

Comment: can i add on this a bit?

Comment: Someone wrote that as an if statement, but why would anyone use it?

Comment: Local declaration of `n` to a lifetime of only the encompassing `if` logical block.

Comment: int cant be used as a bool value though (i'm not talking about 0, and 1)

Comment: It can be used as a bool value, typically `0 == false` and the rest is `true`.

Comment: it really doesnt make sense in my dyslexic head

Comment: You can use an integer as a condition. 0 is equivalent to false and everything else is equivalent to true

Comment: So does the if statement convert an int to a boolean?

Comment: Think of it more as `if ((n = test()) != 0)`

Comment: You're really asking two questions here: 1. Why can you define and initialize a variable like that? and 2. Supposing you can, why does it make sense to have this kind of statement. You are getting some answers to just one of the two questions. FYI.

Comment: @drescherjm This has been around since the early days of C.

Comment: in my opinion this really doesnt make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: you can access the variable in the if statement.

Comment: Consider `if (n = test()) { cout << "hi, I'm the result of test() " << n; }`. `n` exists only for the lifetime of the block, and you don't need to call `test()` twice.

Comment: I found it very handy to write something like that: `if(MyClass* c=maybeReturnNull()) { c->print(); }`. If the expression is `nullptr`, the instruction is bypassed, and the scope of the pointer is just the `if` block.

Comment: It's just a shorthand; a bit of syntactic sugar. There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Who would use `int n = Test()` as an if statement?

It **limits the scope of the `n`**, in the `if` statement, and whoever wants this to have will do so.

---

Now if you ask:

> "Why can you declare and initialize and use a variable like that?"

It is valid because, the C++ standards says so. The [if-statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), the syntax

> attr(*optional*) `if` ( *condition* ) statement-true `else` statement-false
>
> ....
> ***condition***
>
> - one of
>   expression which is contextually [convertible to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)
> - **[declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) of a single non-array variable with a [brace-or-equals initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)**.

Comment: dont really get "declaration of a single non-array variable with a brace-or-equals initializer."

Comment: @TheDogeMaster, Brace: `int n{5}`, equal: `int n = 5`. Notably, you can't use parentheses like you can elsewhere.

Comment: not sure what chris is saying, because i know what the equal sign and {} means

Comment: @TheDogeMaster, Then I mistook which part of the quote you didn't understand.

Comment: i already the basics of c++ (most everything that is commonly used)

Comment: I don't know if the source where JeJo found considered both definitions and declarations

Comment: Declarations would mean that the variable must not be defined.

Comment: ah! i see what you are saying

Comment: @TheDogeMaster, There's more general standard text saying that variable declarations are also definitions except for one particular case (`extern`). Being a definition pretty much means that it's here where the compiler and linker can decide how to manage memory and lifetime for it. Almost all variable declarations you ever come across are definitions.

Comment: i forgot what extern even did. But i could just do a quick google search.

Comment: how would extern (i'm thinking of global variables) not be definitions?
I feel like i'm going way out of the question

Comment: @TheDogeMaster, It's similar to declaring a function without defining it. You tell the compiler that the definition is elsewhere. It's more there for globals. You can still use the variable after declaring it in that case, but it's elsewhere where the compiler and linker will actually know how to figure out the memory details for it. From the programmer's perspective, an extern declaration would give you access to a global variable while ensuring that variable only exists in one place in the program, much like a function.

Comment: OH! I thought extern meant global variable that can be used in any header file.

Comment: I thought that global variables where defined by extern. But i also knew global variables can be used without extern.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a shorthand way to write:

```
{
    int n = Test();
    if (n != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
}
```

So, if `Test()` returned `0` then we don't enter the `if` block, otherwise we do and we'll have `n` to immediately read what it did return, only in that `if`'s scope though.

Note that the integer value in this case can be treated as a boolean, where `0 == false` and anything else is `true`.

Comment: sorry if i am an idiot but how would n be used as a bool value? It doesnt return true or false.

Comment: Integers are evaluatable as bools. 0 is false, everything else is true. In fact, bool types are essentially macros for 0 and 1. It's not clear if your comprehension issue is the _assignment_ / _initialization_ aspect of the code or integers being used in a boolean context. Can you clarify what's confusing, exactly?

Comment: But _why_ can you do this? And why can't you write `if ((int n = Test()) != (int y = 2)) { do_stuff(); }`

Comment: @einpoklum didnt even think of that also

Comment: @einpoklum I wrote an answer based on my judgment of OPs level of experience with C++. I don't think OP is looking for / needs an explanation of that containing standard paper jargon, like you did in your comment on the other answer. I think it's too technical.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the init statement is to limit the scope of variable and allow the *reusing* of values returned by functions. C++17 introduced dedicated init statements for both `if` and `for-each` Sometimes you might want to check if a function failed by returing 0 or nullptr before using the value it returned and you don't want to polute the scope.

```cpp
void foo()
{
   if(int var = some_function(); var != 0)
   {
      // use var
      use_var(var);
   }
   else throw std::exception();
}
```

It may not be that common in the `if` statement but comes more in handy in the `for-each` statement. Look at this example.

```cpp
struct test
{
   std::vector<int> elements;
   auto& items()
   {
      return elements;
   }
}

test get_test()
{
   return {};
}

void foo()
{
   // for(auto e : get_test().items()) - this would cause a new test struct element to be created per each iteration and would invalidate the iterator.
   
   for(auto obj = get_test(); auto e : obj) // test created only once, no iterator invalidation
   {
      std::cout << e << '\n';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition expression you have put in `if` statement is an operation.
If the operation is successful (meaning `n` is declared and is filled with 10), then it is valued as `true`. So it will compile and the `if` statement will be ran.

Comment: I don't remember '=' operators returning true or false.

Comment: @TheDogeMaster: They return a lvalue reference to the left-hand side of the assignment. That can very often be evaluated as an integer value.

Comment: @TheDogeMaster • in C++, zero values are *falsy*, and non-zero values are *truthy*.